# MQA fails after archiving application in XCode

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

Short Version: I'm having issues while archiving my application. The debug works, the archive doesn't. There is nothing to troubleshoot, anyone has ideas?

Log Version:
I have a hybrid worklight app, fully functional and archiving was working just fine until I've added MQA and I'm using iOS.

Versions are:
Worklight 6.2, MQA 6.3, Xcode 6.1, and iOS 8.1.2

Now  I've added MQA following the steps [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFRDS_6.3.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.doc/topics/t_InstallingTheIOSLibraries.html?lang=en).
I've copied the framework into my project directory and added in the other_linked_flags a force load for it.

I've also added a few lines of code to for it to work following the same instructions. Basically everything works just fine when I run it from xcode. When I run the app that xcode deploys on iphone, it the app runs normally and MQA also works.

I only have some kind of problem when I try to archive the app to deploy it in a ad hoc environment.
When I do that the iPhone screen remains black after asking me which user it should use on the MQA. It seems that it can load the webview but can't load the html app.

Unfortunately this doesn't even generate a crash log an as such I'm left in the dark about what is happening.

Can someone give me some light on what can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: You need to work on your question phrasing, the problem is not in the arching (fixed that), but that MQA doesn't work properly after archiving. This can be understand from actually reading your question, and the "short version" is misleading as well.

Comment: Also, I believe MQA 6.3 should be used with MobileFirst Platform 6.3, and not with Worklight 6.2

Comment: Idan, actually with MQA is the only thing that works after the archiving. I do agree with you, I could use some lessons in expression thou.

Comment: Does the application work after archiving, if you do *not* add MQA?

Comment: Yes. If I comment out the line that enabled MQA, the result of archiving works just fine.

Comment: So on the surface it seems that indeed it is MQA that fails the application.

Comment: I guess so.. Let me add some info. When I install the app that results from the archive, the MQA seems to work; as in, if I shake the device I can file  a bug report. However before I created this post here, I've had another issue which was, whenever I launched the app it crashed immediately. I've solved this by adding the "OTHER_LINKED_FLAG" that the documentation mentions. Now I'm at the point of this post and I'm only referring this because I believe my actual problem might be something close, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: For the sake of testing, can you try the same with Studio 6.3?

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to integration the wrong library into your project.

Right now it looks like you are working on a Hybrid app but try adding the native libraries into it, which is incorrect.

If you are working on a Hybrid app, you need to download the Hybrid SDK.
If you are working on a Native iOS app, you need to add the native library

There is a library specific to Hybrid apps. You can find it in the following link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFRDS_6.3.0/com.ibm.mqa.uau.doc/topics/t_download_wrklight_libraries.html?lang=en

All what is required is to do is removing the native library if added, and integrate the worklight SDK into the app code under the common folder in the main.js file.

Comment: Idan, the javascript toolkit for MQA is very jerky and slugish.
Nevertheless, there is nothing wrong with customizing some part of a app with native code, it's like adding a new feature to cordova if we abuse the language a bit. 
I don't think this is a worklight issue, or a MQA issue or anything like that, I believe my problem is around what I've doing for a distribution build on xcode.

Comment: Perhaps, but the mix you're trying to do is not a supporter path.